# How to disable SSO only for a specific application in yammer?

Tags: single-sign-on, yammer

I want to use yammer api in my app. For that I created yammer app from https://www.yammer.com/client_applications and then called link 
https://www.yammer.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=[:client_id]&redirect_uri=[:redirect_uri]&response_type=token 
as described in yammer documentation.

The problem is when i enter the mail address i am redirected to SSO platform of the enterprise.

Is there a possibility to disable SSO only for this app ?
Or is there any way to avoid redirection to SSO platform ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to disable SSO at the app level. All user authentication request must go through the SSO flow if SSO is enabled for the yammer network.